# Delete a node in a linked list Python

Tags: python

I encounter these two situations and I don't know why they are different. Assuming there is a linked list, and we have to delete a given node (the node is neither the head nor the tail of the linked list).

There are two ways to do this:

```
node = node.next
```

```
node.next = node.next.next
```

May I ask what is the difference? The first doesn't work at all. Thank you

Comment: Can you add more information about your implementation? May be share it so we can help

Comment: The first one modifies a local `node` variable and doesn't affect the list structure.  The second one modifies the `next` attribute of `node` such that it points at the *next* `next` node, meaning that the original `next` is no longer part of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first statement, `node` is just a variable. If you're not using that variable as the head of the linked list, then assigning to it can't affect the linked list.

In the second statement, by assigning to an attribute, you're mutating an object. As long as some other node in the list has a reference to that object, your change will be preserved.